# Returning back to original details viewcontroller after creating new entry two viewcontrollers deep with Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I have what I believe (though I could be wrong) to be a pretty standard setup for adding a new record in iOS with Swift:

[image: Screenshot of main storyboard]

As you can see, we have a navigation controller at the beginning which has the AddAnItemVC (a UITableViewController) as the root controller with a segue.

When someone clicks on Project, we segue over to the SelectProjectViewController, which is another UITableViewController.  Since it's embedded in the original UINavigationController, we can't directly add buttons via xcode IB so we are programatically adding a button to the top right to add a new project.  If they select a project from the list, we are using a delegate/prototype to return the value of that selection back to the AddAnItemVC.  That works fine.

Now if the user selects the Add button in the nav bar, we perform a segue to open up the AddANewProjectVC, another UITableViewController, and programatically add a SAVE button to the nav.  Here is where we are stuck.

We want it so that when the user clicks the SAVE button we immediately jump back to the original AddAnItemVC view controller with the newly created project selected (i.e. displayed in the static cell for Project).  We cant figure out how to do that.  We're moving back form the SelectAProjectVC to the AddAnItemVC using

```
 if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

but if we do that here we only move back ONE level to the SelectAProjectVC, not the original details one.

How can we get back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AddAnItemVC is set as root to navigation controller. You can directly move to it using

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

You can load the data in ViewWillAppear() method

Comment: That's awesome. What do you mean load the data in view did appear?  The data I set through the protocol?  Also, is this the standard way of doing these type of flows or am I bastardizing how it should be done?

Comment: This is the standard way. You can directly pop to particular view controller if it's present in Navigation controller stack.

Comment: As you want to select newly created project, you need to write selection logic i.e call selectRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
                 animated animated: Bool,
           scrollPosition scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition)

Comment: For "newly created project selected" : ViewWillAppear() method will be useful for displaying the newly created project. Please mark it as correct if that work for you.

Comment: @AnkitaShah excellent.  In going to select your answer but can you tell me so I know how do I jump to ANY previous VC in the stack by id, tag or whatever is the normal way?  Thx.

Comment: @JoshL http://www.iosrocketsurgery.com/2013/12/ios-pop-to-specific-view-controller.html#.VlVeS98rKu4 this link will give you brief about it. You can use it as per you'r requirement